# HMAC validation Failure with code 403

Tags: c#, hmac

I have been exploring payeezy api from last three days. I am just making a simple http web request from a C# application. I have followed all the steps mentions and correctly verified each and everything. Below is the detail per item.

1. API Key :- I have verified my api key its correct.
2. API Secret :- It is also correct.
3. merchant token :- It is also verified.
4. Nonce :- I have created cryptographically strong random number as following.

   ```
   RandomNumberGenerator rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
   byte[] nonceData = new byte[18];
   rng.GetBytes(nonceData);
   string nonce = BitConverter.ToUInt64(nonceData,0).ToString();
   ```
5. Timestamp :-

   ```
   string timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalMilliseconds).ToString();
   ```
6. Payload :-

   ```
   {"merchant_ref":"Astonishing-Sale","transaction_type":"authorize","method":"credit_card","amount":"1299","currency_code":"USD","credit_card":{"type":"visa","cardholder_name":"John Smith","card_number":"4788250000028291","exp_date":"1020","cvv":"123"}}
   ```
7. Then I have created HMAC as following.

   ```
   private string CreateAuthorization(string data, string secret)
   {
       // data is in following format.
       //  data = apiKey + nonce + timestamp + token + payload;
       secret = secret ?? "";
       using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret)))
       {
           byte[] hashdata = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(data));
           return Convert.ToBase64String(hashdata);
       }
   }
   ```
8. Now I am getting hmac validation error. My generated hmac string is 64 bit while on your website under docs and sandbox its 86 bit.

Can you please assist me in this as I am stuck on this issue from last three days.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the common causes for “HMAC validation Failure”:

1. API key and/or API secret are incorrect.
2. Leading or trailing spaces in the API key, API secret, merchant token.
3. Timestamp in the HTTP header is not in milliseconds.
4. Timestamp in the HTTP header does not represent EPOCH time.
5. Timestamp in the HTTP header is not within 5 minutes of our server time.
6. System time is not accurate.

Here is a sample c# code to generate HMAC:

```
public byte[] CalculateHMAC(string data, string secret)
    {
        HMAC hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));
        byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        byte[] hmac2Hex = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(hmac2Hex);
        hex = hex.Replace("-","").ToLower();
        byte[] hexArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hex);
        return hexArray;
    }

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                     
    string jsonString = "{ \"merchant_ref\": \"MVC Test\", \"transaction_type\": \"authorize\", \"method\": \"credit_card\", \"amount\": \"1299\", \"currency_code\": \"USD\", \"credit_card\": { \"type\": \"visa\", \"cardholder_name\": \"Test Name\", \"card_number\": \"4005519200000004\", \"exp_date\": \"1020\", \"cvv\": \"123\" } }";

    Random random = new Random();
    string nonce = (random.Next(0, 1000000)).ToString();

    DateTime date = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan span = (date - epoch);
    string time = span.TotalSeconds.ToString();

    string token = Request.Form["token"];//Merchant token
    string apiKey = Request.Form["apikey"];//apikey
    string apiSecret = Request.Form["apisecret"];//API secret
    string hashData = apiKey+nonce+time+token+jsonString;

    string base64Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(CalculateHMAC(hashData, apiSecret));

    string url = "https://api-cert.payeezy.com/v1/transactions";

    //begin HttpWebRequest
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.Accept = "*/*";
    webRequest.Headers.Add("timestamp", time);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("nonce", nonce);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("token", token);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("apikey", apiKey);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", base64Hash );
    webRequest.ContentLength = jsonString.Length;
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

    StreamWriter writer = null;
    writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
    writer.Write(jsonString);
    writer.Close();

    string responseString;
    try
        {
            using(HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseString = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
                    request_label.Text = "<h3>Request</h3><br />" + webRequest.Headers.ToString() + System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(jsonString);
                    response_label.Text = "<h3>Response</h3><br />" + webResponse.Headers.ToString() + System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(responseString);
                }
            }
        }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Response != null) 
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response) 
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream())) 
                {
                    string remoteEx = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    error.Text = remoteEx;
                }
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: I have copied your code and only put in my values for token, apiKey, and apiSecret but still I am getting HMAC validation error :(

Comment: I have compared both total number of milliseconds from Payeezy website and the one I am generating. Below are the totals. 1) Payeezy: 1439268787215 2) Mine: 1439268783429 The little difference is due to time elapsed during copying from VS and Payeezy website.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on an integration and it's working great; maybe you can take a peek
https://github.com/clifton-io/Clifton.Payment

Specifically you'll want to look here:
https://github.com/clifton-io/Clifton.Payment/blob/cc4053b0bfe05f2453dc508e96a649fc138b973c/Clifton.Payment/Gateway/Payeezy/PayeezyGateway.cs#L66

Best of luck :)